# What is the best way to recommend a new browser to my family?

Tags: web-browser

I have a hard time encouraging family members who are non-technical (like my mother, who is confused when her notebook presses on a key on her keyboard or my grandmother who has a hard time grasping the purpose of the internet at large) to use newer or different versions of their existing browser. This includes merely upgrading IE, or using something like Firefox and Chrome.

I have on occasion resorted to updating the browser personally via remote support session, setting it as the default, and changing the icon to the IE e, but I do consider that to be a little unethical. I tell myself that it's for the best as it prevents confusion, they don't understand well enough to know why I'm doing it, and it prevents some of the more malicious attacks.

What have you found is the best way to get your non-technical family to use a new browser, and how do you encourage them to not be afraid of the tool?

Comment: For further information: I'm a 34 year old professional software (web, services) developer who interfaces with clients on a regular basis at a fairly successful online software company. I am second/third tier support and often do browser based troubleshooting. I have been using the internet since 1997 and my family have known I was the go-to guy for software/computer questions since then. I am not 13, this is not my first computer, I'm just looking for a better way to encourage people to use something more modern.

Comment: Also, this may or may not be helpful to me in a professional role where I adapt the styles given as answers into work documents to propose to the management here for relay to first-tier services to use in assisting clients directly.

Comment: I've used the old change-the-icon trick before, and I must say it works splendidly ;)

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing the *software* recommendation request in this question - could you clarify that?

Comment: @Undo. It's not a request for software at all, its a request for a method of recommending software when the receiving party isn't convinced they have a problem or savvy enough to undertake fixing it without some pressure in the right places. And as such **I think it is on topic good-subjective style question that is relevant to experts in this field.**

Comment: @Undo This site is about software recommendations, which I feel this is a good class of question. I don't know that it fits many genre of software, such as "word processor" or "FPS game", whereas most of us have come across the browser upgrade issue, especially when confronted with IE8 or lower and malicious security holes.

Comment: There is a [meta question](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/703/83) discussing this question.

Comment: @jcolebrand, This question is easily on-topic. Update this question to ask for a software that you can use to update your family's browsers then flag it for re-open.

Comment: @Pacerier while I am grateful for the advice, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are you able to help me with a community edit to get me on the right track and then I can "cole-ify" it?